# Convert JMS out bound channel adapter to equavalent Spring Integration DSL in java 1.7

Tags: jms, spring-integration, dsl, spring-jms

How can I convert `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="topicChannel" destination="requestQueue"/>` to equivalent [Spring Integration DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/spring-integration-java-dsl-reference) in java 1.7

Below is the ActiveMQ configuration:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="requestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="queue.demo"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
  <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
   <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
   </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="requestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
  <constructor-arg value="queue.demo"/>
 </bean>

Comment: Don't put XML in comments; it doesn't render well - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public ActiveMQQueue requestQueue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue("queue.demo");
}
```

etc.

Comment: Gary thanks for the reply....Can you please tell me what is the DSL configuration for **<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="topicChannel" destination="requestQueue"/>**

Comment: See the [DSL documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#adapters) and [test cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/jms/JmsTests.java#L195) for configuration examples.

Comment: Basically my main aim is to convert the below snipplet to spring DSL ><int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="topicChannel" >destination="requestQueue"/>

   > <int:channel id="listenerChannel" />

    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="messageDrivenAdapter" channel="listenerChannel"
                                            destination="requestQueue"/>

    ><int:service-activator input-channel="listenerChannel" >ref="messageListener" method="processMessage" />

Comment: I have asked you before not to post XML in comments; it's unreadable. Try reading the documentation and test cases as I've suggested; if you still can't figure it out, ask a specific question; do not ask us to do all your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the sender like this:

```
    @Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sample.dispatcher" })
public class DispatcherConfig {

    public static final String JOB_TOPIC = "jobTopic";

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = JOB_TOPIC)
    public MessageHandler outboundJmsAdapter(JmsTemplate template) {
        JmsSendingMessageHandler handler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(template);
        handler.setDestinationName(JOB_TOPIC);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean(name = JOB_TOPIC)
    public MessageChannel jobTopic() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }
}
```

and the listener like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sample.processor" })
@IntegrationComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sample.processor" })
public class ProcessorConfig {

    public static final String ON_POST_JOB = "onPostJob";

    public static final String JOB_TOPIC = "jobTopic";

    @Bean
    public Queue jobTopic() {

        return new ActiveMQQueue(JOB_TOPIC);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint inboundJmsAdapter(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        return new JmsMessageEndpointBuilder()
                .setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
                .setDestination(JOB_TOPIC)
                .setInputChannel(onPostJob())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = ON_POST_JOB)
    public MessageChannel onPostJob() {

        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

}
```

I have a sample project that uses jms and Spring Integration as form of communication between two applications running on separate vm/process/:

https://github.com/vineey/sample-jobqueue